# While creating robot framework project in Eclipse, a buiding failed and shows XML-RPC error

Tags: java, python-3.x, eclipse, robotframework

I am using

- python 3.11
- jdk 11
- Eclipse latest verson
- Then RED from eclipse market place.

also i had insalled robot framework using pip command in command prompt

- pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary

and hence while creating new robot project gets XML-RPC error, can anyone please help?

Thanks! in advance.

I had stop the following services and set to automatic

DCOM
Rpc Locator
RpcSs

Also I had check Java path and python path

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: check your eclipse and java version, they should either be 32-bit or same.